# How to prevent wunderbar_emporium rootkit

Tags: linux, rootkit

I just learned about the `wunderbar_emporium` rootkit, and it sounds pretty nasty. I tested it on a few linux servers I have access to, and while it failed on two of them, it was successful on one with kernel 2.6.9-78.0.13.ELsmp. What's the best way to prevent this rootkit? Does kernel  2.6.9-89.0.11.ELsmp resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the RedHat Security Advisory [RHSA-2009:1457](http://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2009-1457.html) kernel 2.6.18-92.1.28 resolves the issue on RHEL 5.2.z. As you're inquiring about a 2.6.9 kernel I'm making the assumption you're on RHEL4 and [RHSA-2009:1469](https://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2009-1469.html) mentions 2.6.9-78.0.27 for RHEL 4.7.z though the original RHEL4 advisory [RHSA-2009:1223](https://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2009-1223.html) mentions 2.6.9-89.0.9.

For the full listing of Security Advisories issued by RedHat regarding [CVS-2009-2692](https://www.redhat.com/security/data/cve/CVE-2009-2692.html) that wunderbar_emporium is taking advantage of.