# rootkit exploit on centos server

Tags: centos, hacking, rootkit

I have recenrly found a file in my folder

called wunderbar_emporium

its details is [here](http://www.packetstormsecurity.org/filedesc/wunderbar_emporium-tgz.html)

What is that , how it came here and what should i check to make sure what arong has been done to system

Comment: Make a copy so you can analyse it later then nuke it from space and reinstall from a known good backup. [This](http://serverfault.com/questions/72986/how-to-prevent-wunderbar-emporium-rootkit) SF question and other related questions may be of help to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try installing rkhunter and/or chkrootkit. But: it might be too late, who knows which files already were modified?

I know it sucks, but:

- Take the machine offline
- Try to find out what happened
- Reinstall machine and take countermeasures right at the start (file change detection programs like fcheck, aide etc)